# ABNT2 keyboard for Android x86 2.2 r2 sparta "distro"

Tags: keyboard

I'm using Oracle Virtual Box to emulate an Android-x86 device. I installed android-x86-2.2-r2-sparta.iso to a virtual HD. Then I changed config to put it in Portuguese (Brazil) language. It is ok until that point.

But in keyboard options there isn't ABNT2 keyboard layout, so some keys are missmatch the machine keyboard (e.g. "ç", "{", "}"...).

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at alternative input methods (keyboard apps) that specifically support Portuguese language.

I personally used [AnySoftKeyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard), which does have a [Portuguese language pack](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.portuguese).  There are [many](https://market.android.com/search?q=portuguese%20keyboard&c=apps) other similar keyboard apps on the Market as well.  You might need to get them elsewhere though, since your build most likely doesn't have the Android Market access.

Comment: do u know any alternative for non-homologated devices, like chinese tablets?

Comment: As long as you can side-load APKs, you should be able to install keyboard apps on any supported Android OS version.